# How to include external html in Nuxt app from object in js file with http url provided by bot constructor?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I try to include a bot developed with landbot.io in my nuxt web app (NUXT.js framework).
Below, there is the code that the landbot's guide provides me.

Code to include:

```
<script src="https://static.landbot.io/landbot-widget/landbot-widget-1.0.0.js"></script>
<div id="myLandbot" style="width: 100%; height: 500px"></div>
<script>
  var myLandbot = new LandbotFrameWidget({
    container: '#myLandbot',
    index: 'https://landbot.io/u/..../index.html',
 });
</script>
```

But i don't know what i should do with the second script tag because i always get this error:

> "LandbotFrameWidget do not definied"

I include the first script tag in nuxt.config.js like that:

```
head: {
    script: [
      { src: 'https://static.landbot.io/umicore/UmiAccessPoint.js' },
      { src: 'https://static.landbot.io/landbot-widget/landbot-widget-1.0.0.js' }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `nuxt.config.js` config is correct, but the first script src is not needed.

I've created a working example in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/codesandbox-nuxt-7jix1), take a look at the code used in the `index.vue` file:

```html
<template>
  <section>
    <div>
      <div id="myLandbot" style="width: 100vw; height: 100vh"></div>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
    var myLandbot = new LandbotFrameWidget({
      container: "#myLandbot",
      index: "https://landbot.io/u/H-117144-ZGUSSI5IM2OI5NYH/index.html"
    });
  }
};
</script>
```

Hope it helps!